# How to integrate Magento into Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, magento-1.7, integrate

I want to integrate Magento to a wordpress site. I tried with this plugin. http://wordpress.org/plugins/magento-wordpress-integration/ But after installation nothing changed.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did it the other way, integrate Wordpress in Magento > http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-wordpress-integration.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. But my requirement is entirely opposite what you have mentioned

Comment: Well, you asked for a suggestion ;) Did you follow these steps: http://www.mwi-plugin.com/documentation/installation/ ?

Comment: Did you Google it? Page 1 result, an extensive set of answers which covers this and @gelleby 's suggestion too http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7112/what-is-the-best-strategy-to-integrate-wordpress-inside-of-magento

Comment: @McNab  : That is NOT what I want. I'm asking the opposite of it. How to integrate Magento into WordPress?

Comment: Forget it. I have no idea why anybody would try and do that but you are essentially trying to convert an enterprise level Zend Framework application into a Wordpress Plugin.  Wordpress is by far the more lightweight application which is why everybody else is integrating that into Magento, not the other way round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the creator of Magento WordPress Integration for WordPress. You say that nothing changed after installaition...

That's exactly right. You need to then implement the blocks you want to include throughout your theme files using the code provided in the documentation: http://www.mwi-plugin.com/documentation/template-functions/

Please bear in mind that this doesn't allow you to avoid the Magento frontend altogether, and you will never find a plugin that does that. if that is what you require, then use something like WooCommerce, or use the FishPig extension, as suggested by others.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. It helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You just download fishpig extension (http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/) and install in your Magento after that you have to download WordPress (https://wordpress.org/download/) and install it into the same database as Magento And now it will work. After that in your Magento admin you can see in your top menu WordPress link is there. (Wordpress->setting) and then you can find your blog url. You can check it will be work.

Answer (score 0):

Fishpig is the best option for magento word press integration.

The magento store can boast powerful performance as well as elegant appearance if these two platforms are merged. I have found this another article for magento wordpress integration mentioning few techniques for integration - http://opensourceforu.com/2016/12/integrate-magento-store-into-wordpress-blog/